# Convert JavaScript AJAX to HttpWebRequest code

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net, .net, asp.net-ajax

I need imitate AJAX call to web service in my console application. Is there any way to do this with HttpWebRequest?

Source request:

> var webRequest = Sys.Net.WebServiceProxy.invoke('http://webserver.com/WS_Message.asmx', 'MyMethod', false, {p1:aa,p2:bb,p3:123}, onSuccess, onFailure, userContext, timeout, enableJsonp, jsonpCallbackParameter);

Sample that doesn't work:

```
HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest) WebRequest.Create("http://webserver.com/WS_Message.asmx/MyMethod");
request.Method = "POST";
request.ContentType = "application/json; charset=utf-8";

byte[] _bytes= Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes("{p1:aa,p2:bb,p3:123}");

request.ContentLength = _bytes.Length;

Stream stream = request.GetRequestStream();
stream.Write(_bytes, 0, _bytes.Length);
stream.Close();

HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse) request.GetResponse();

using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream()))
{
    Console.WriteLine(reader.ReadToEnd());
}
```

Comment: Could you post some more information about what you expecting and what you are currently getting back?

Comment: Already solved my issue. Was related to incorrect headers.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you were calling into a (.NET based) web service in javascript. Why not simply add a web reference to your console app, and call it that way ?

It will be much less work than trying to replicate the web service call manually through an HttpWebRequest.

Answer (score 0):

I had to use Chrome Developer Console to see correct http headers. My issue was related to incorrect JSON string format.

> @"{""p1"": ""aa"", ""p2"": ""bb"", ""p3"": 123}"